# Best way to convert Tensor from [24, 512, 768, 1] to [24, 512, 14, 14]

Tags: python, pytorch

I had an incompatibility issue with `PyTorch` tensor shape. Hence, I need to convert one tensor from shape `[24, 512, 768, 1]` to `[24, 512, 14, 14]`.
What is the best way while trying to preserve as much info as possible about the original tensor representation?

Comment: It cant be possible because the product of the lengths of the dimensions of the first tensor does not match the second one.

Comment: I meant using for example convolution, upsampling, maxpoooling ....etc

Comment: What rule do you want to use in order to determine where the data goes? We cannot choose a "best way" for you, or know what "preserves as much info as possible", because we don't have any metrics for "preservation", or know what the important features of your data are. We don't even know why the input has this shape in the first place, or why you need the other shape. [Please try to do some research first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) based on your specific needs, and possible *try some things*.

Comment: In [tag:pytorch] : `torch.reshape(torch.rand(24,512,768,1)[...,:196,:], (24,512,14,14))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an optimal solution, regardless of the *data preservation* you want to include:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.constant([[[[1]]*768]*512]*24)
t = tf.reshape(tf.constant(t.numpy()[:, :, :196]), (24, 512, 14, 14))
print(t.shape)
```

**Output:**

```
(24, 512, 14, 14)
```